# Test Facebook Insights Install tracking on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-insights

I've been following the instructions here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/#advanced

I've made sure my app is not in Sandbox mode, because if it was I was getting:

`throw new FacebookException("No attribution id available to send to server.");`

Now I'm not seeing install events reported, I think it's throwing the exception:
`throw new FacebookException("No attribution id available to send to server.");`

Is there no way to report installs to FB insights without attribution (I believe my iOS devices were sending it with no attribution)

Answer (score 4):

I had this error until I installed the Facebook app on my device, and logged into it. After that I could see an install event reported.